# How do I verify incoming payment for web based service in XMR?

Tags: payment-integration, payment

What are my options if I want to build a web based service with XMR payment gateway?

Comment: OK so I see there are APIs for XMR for checking blocks. How could I decode amount from the block with my view key having tx id?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the *wallet* RPC interface, not daemon RPC.

Therefore, if you are going to be using payment IDs you can use [get_payments](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_payments), or if you plan to use subaddresses per customer/order you can use [incoming_transfers](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#incoming_transfers) to monitor incoming transactions by subaddress.